Casting in C - confused
I have a tiny little code snipplet here:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
void main(void)


{
int clouds=15;
double  
    Zenith_rad=1.1827,
    Normal_direct=774.6839,
    A=0, B=0, C=0;      

A = Normal_direct * cos(Zenith_rad);
B = A * ( 1 - ( clouds / 100)) ;
C = A * ( 1 - ( 0.15)) ;
printf("A: %f\n" ,A);
printf("B: %f\n" ,B);
printf("C: %f\n" ,C);
}

Expected result:
A: 293.161306
B: 249.187110
C: 249.187110

Seen result:
A: 293.161306
B: 293.161306
C: 249.187110

Adding a (double) cast in front of clouds makes it working.
Why?

You are dealing with integer division

clouds/100 is an integer division and results to 0.

clouds / 100 performs integer division, i.e. 15 / 100, which produces the integer 0 as a result.  (double) clouds / 100 converts clouds to a double, and 100 to a double, then performs double division, i.e. 15.0 / 100.0, producing a nonzero double result (approximately 0.15, but the result is not exact).

And what is the correct usage?

@Christian If you want to force double division, the normal way to write it would be with double constants, e.g. clouds / 100.0, or (double) clouds / 100.0, both of which will perform double division.
